# Reading from blocking queue with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I have a producer-consumer model using a blocking queue where 4 threads read files from a directory puts it to the blocking queue and 4 threads(consumer) reads from blocking queue.

My problem is every time only one consumer reads from the Blockingqueue and the other 3 consumer threads are not reading:

```
        final BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(QUEUE_SIZE);

            CompletableFuture<Void> completableFutureProducer = produceUrls(files, queue, checker);
//not providing code for produceData , it is working file with all 4 //threads writing to Blocking queue. Here is the consumer code.

    private CompletableFuture<Validator> consumeData(
            final Response checker,
            final CompletableFuture<Void> urls
    ) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(checker, 4)
                .whenComplete((result, err) -> {
                    if (err != null) {
                        LOG.error("consuming url worker failed!", err);
                        urls.cancel(true);
                    }
    });


    }
  completableFutureProducer.join();
            completableFutureConsumer.join();
```

This is my code. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or help with correct code.
Why is one consumer reading from the Blocking queue.

Adding code for Response class reading from Blocking queue :

```
    @Slf4j
    public final class Response implements Supplier<Check> {
        private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> data;
        private final AtomicBoolean producersComplete;
        private final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    
        public ResponseCode(
                final BlockingQueue<byte[]> data
        ) {
            this.data = data;
            producersDone = new AtomicBoolean();
    
        }
public void notifyProducersDone() {
    producersComplete.set(true);
}

        @Override
        public Check get() {
            try {
                Check check = null;
                try {
                    while (!data.isEmpty() || !producersDone.get()) {
                        final byte[] item = data.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        if (item != null) {
                           LOG.info("{}",new String(item));
// I see only one thread printing result here .
                            validator = validateData(item);
                        }
                    }
        
                } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    throw new WriteException("Exception occurred while data validation", e);
        
                } 
                return check;
            } finally {
                LOG.info("Done reading data from BlockingQueue");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont see any code that would try to take from the queue nor put something into it.

Comment: just added . Please see the edit now

Comment: @Antoniossss looks like I am doing everything correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose from this alone, but it's probably not correct to check for `data.isEmpty()` because the queue may happen to be temporarily empty (but later get items). So your threads might exit as soon as they encounter a temporarily empty queue.

Instead, you can exit if producers were done AND you got an empty result from the `poll`. That way the threads only exit when there are truly no more items to process.

It's a bit odd though that you are returning the result of the last item (alone). Are you sure this is what you want?

*EDIT:* I've done something very similar recently. [Here](https://github.com/eshioji/hotvect/blob/192801c37e460d5afc08d4bcf5172b88ae47930a/hotvect-util/src/main/java/com/eshioji/hotvect/util/CpuIntensiveFileTransformer.java#L75) is a class that reads from a file, transforms the lines in a multi-threaded way, then writes to a different file (the order of lines are preserved).
It also uses a `BlockingQueue`. It's very similar to your code, but it doesn't check for `quue.isEmpty()` for the aforementioned reason. It works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for commenting , I am returning validator result for every item. Not sure what you meant by "the result of the last item". Can you help me understand?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are ending up returning the validator for the last item only - you are discarding all the other ones. If you want to retain results for all of them, you have to do something different.

Comment: I did something very similar recently, so added link to that code. Hope that helps, too. @Coder123

Comment: I removed queue.isEmpty() and still I see only one consumer thread reading from the queue. I checked your code , but still not sure why I am returning only last item.

Comment: You need to check even if producers are done (not balk if the producers are done). So you store the result of `producersDone.get()`, and then exist if ` && queue.poll == null`. @Coder123

Comment: As to the retuning of only one item, try declaring `validator` as `final` and you'll see it's being re-assigned. If you don't send the reference anywhere before it gets re-assigned, you must be losing it. @Coder123

Answer (score 2):

4+4 threads is not that many, so you better  do not use asynchronous tools like CompletableFuture. Simple multithreaded program would be simpler and work faster.

Having

```
 BlockingQueue<byte[]> data;
```

don't use `data.poll()`;

use `data.take();`

Answer (score 0):

When you have lets say 1 item in the queue, and 4 consumers, one of them will poll the item rendering queue to be empty. Then 3 of the rest of the consumers checks if `queue.isEmpty()`, and since it is - quits the loop.